# prefs.set, prefs.getString not working in google gadgets

Tags: javascript, google-gadget

I am initialising the user prefs and i am setting and getting numeric prefs but i do not seems to be able to get and set string prefs. the prefs i initialise are not altered later on in the gadget, but int prefs are.

i set the  user pref up
 
the set the actual value
        prefs.set("Cpopup8_value",popup8_value);
later in the app the value can be changed

but when accessing it  later it is still the original default value
         popup8_value = prefs.getString("Cpopup8_value");

i have checked that i am actually writing the correct value which seems to be the case and i have also checked i have not exceeded the 2k limit.

Storing and retrieving integers works fine.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?  Can you post a bit more of your code?

Comment: No because i was doing at a paid app and the company i was doing it for decided not to use it. However i am not sure if it was dropping the prefs or whether i was programming it incorrectly. The information on the Google dev site implied there was a problem but that it had been solved at least a year before my problems with it. The difficulty is effectively debugging in these situations. For prefs with Mac widgets you can go and inspect the widget plist and verify. with google being in an xml file in a frame etc i could not find any way other than trial and error to work it out.

Comment: Sorry, ran out of space. I did start to write a small iGoogle widget without the complexity of the full app i was working on just to test it but i never got round to fully testing it. I could see if i can find it if you were interested.